# Pasar al siguiente Textbox mediante Enter en un TabControl

Tags: c#, tab

necesito que al entrar en un tabPage determinado en c# y tengo el foco en un TextBox determinado, utilizando la instrucción selectNextControl me pase al siguiente control. No he encontrado la solución en internet por ello lo posteo por si alguien ha tenido un problema igual y lo ha resuelto. He intentado hacer lo siguiente pero nada de nada. Gracias

```
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    public static void _controlSiguiente(TabControl tabControl, Control.ControlCollection controls,  Form form, object sender)
    {
        foreach (TabPage page in tabControl.TabPages)
        {
            foreach (Control control in page.Controls)
            {
                if (control is TextBox)
                {
                    control.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cuando ejecutas este metodo?

Comment: En tu pregunta no está claro lo que deseas lograr. Tu código, lo que hará es recorrer todos los objetos `TabPage`,  en cada `TabPage` recorre todos los controles y por cada uno que encuentre de tipo `TextBox`ejecutará el método `SelectNextControl`. Esa es la lógica de tu código, de esa forma lograras que tu función seleccione realmente el ultimo control según el orden de tabulador `tab order`, que se encuentre después  de un control de tipo `TextBox` dentro del ultimo objeto `TabPage` de la colección `tabControl.TabPages`. Otro comportamiento deseado, requiere otra lógica de programación.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte se requiere clarificar tu pregunta, pues como bien dice @gbianchi es necesario conocer desde que contexto llamas a tu método  `_controlSiguiente`, al no saber el contexto de donde lo llamas no sabemos que significa la variable `object sender` que pasas como argumento a la función `SelectNextControl`, además declaras dos variables que no se usan para nada `Control.ControlCollection controls,  Form form`.

Comment: Yo ejecuto este método al darle enter sobre un Textbox que se encuentra dentro de un TabPage

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que pretendes es que cuando salgas de un control textbox se dirija a un Tabcontrol?

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 TuTabControl.SelectedIndex = 3; // acá indicas el index del control que necesitas estar seleccionado
}
```

Es lo que entendí  de tu pregunta

Comment: No, yo lo que quiero es que al darle enter sobre un textbox que está en el primer TabPage se diriga al siguiente control textbox que está debajo de este Si fuera un formulario normal sin tabControl si lo puedo hacer pero al tener un TabControl es un poco diferente y no sabría como hacerlo con SelectNextControl

Comment: @SergioDavidPerezAcosta la tecla [tab] funciona para que pase el siguiente control?